# Highchart line graph - Parse json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm trying to parse an external json and create this line graph. If I use the JSON below on the page, it works well but if I use an external JSON file with the same data, it doesn't work.

```
var data = [{"name":"Efficiency","data":[215, 226, 210]}];
```

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON('/public/history/1800999999', function(data) {


var myChart = Highcharts.chart('containerCharts', {     

    title: {
        text: 'Lorem Ipsum'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Lorem Ipsum'
    },


    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Dollar Amount'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },


    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 1983
        }
    },
    chart:{ 
        height: 500

    },


    series: data

});

});
```

I'm not sure why it's not working with the data in an external JSON file.

Comment: Have you checked `Network` tab of your browser? Does it really return correct json?

Comment: I did. The response i get from the variable data is: 
{"name":"Efficiency","data":[215,226,209,215,221,2]}

Comment: @Core972 is right, either data must be an array or use `series: [data]`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3fcwuj7s/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cline%3E.data) `data` must be an array not an object :

```
var data =  {"name":"Efficiency","data":[215,226,209,215,221,2]}; // Not working
var data =  [{"name":"Efficiency","data":[215,226,209,215,221,2]}]; // Will works
```

Here a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/om7tLx1b/)